# Selenium webdriver with python throws requests.exceptions.MissingSchema

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The following error is raised when running the below script:

> requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema
>   supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?

I saw one solution which said to find elements by xpath but as I said I am new I am unable to replicate the code.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get("https://charities.govt.nz/")
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
print("Number of links : %s" %len(links))

for link in links:
    r = requests.head(link.get_attribute('href'))
    print(link.get_attribute('href'), r.status_code)
```

A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issues were being caused by invalid links on that website (i.e. there is a link that's an empty string). I've modified your code to work with that using an `if-statement` within the `for-loop` to check that the link starts with `http` (so it will also ignore the `mailto` link on that website).

I've also modified how the links are being retrieved and stored. The links are retrieved from the web page using `xpath`. The links are stored in a list of unique `strings` rather than a list of `firefoxWebElements` (i.e. increasing usability and removing duplicate links).

```py
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get("https://charities.govt.nz/")

# This variable contains all the links found
all_links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")]

# This variable contains all unique links (i.e. removes duplicates)
unique_links = list(dict.fromkeys(all_links))

print("Number of links : %s" %len(all_links))
print("Number of unique links : %s" %len(unique_links))

for link in unique_links:
    # If the link is easy to work with
    if link.startswith("http"):
        req = requests.head(link)
        print(link, req.status_code)
    else:
        print("Ignoring '{}'".format(link))
```

Comment: some marked my question as duplicate but the solutions they provided don't work with my scenario. So. thank you @Tyler for replying. While running your statement I am getting "AttributeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'startswith" Can you please suggest. I am very new to programming it takes me hours just to resolve one error.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer. It was laziness on my part as I was using `link` as a `string` datatype when it is actually a `FirefoxWebElement`. The above code now stores the `href` in a string via `link_url = link.get_attribute('href')` allowing you to use and manipulate `link_url`.

Comment: it still comes up with the same error.   File "C:\Users\dharg\PycharmProjects\BrokenLinks\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 387, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?
How can I share the whole result with you?

Comment: someone mentioned this in a different post "When finding the element by TAG_NAME it shows me the same error but for XPATH it works. the solution mentioned was: links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='rc']//h3//ancestor::a[1]")))
but how do I use it in my case. Again thank you Tyler for your help

Comment: @G.Dhar, I've once again updated the answer. The real issue was that there was a link on the page with empty string. I've used a simple `if-statement` to ignore this and other "hard-to-deal-with" links so you can keep moving forward with this project. I have also changed the way links are obtained to use `xpath` so you can see how it works for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you @Tyler for your help.